# What is the runner's average acceleration during the first 4.1s?

Tags: physics

A world-class sprinter accelerates to his maximum speed in 4.1s . He then maintains this speed for the remainder of a 100-m race, finishing with a total time of 9.0s. What is the runner's average acceleration during the first 4.1s ?

I know that average velocity is $\frac{\Delta v}{\Delta t}$, where $\Delta t =4.1s$. I also know that the initial velocity is 0, but I don't know how to find the final velocity to find the average velocity. Can someone please help me?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let denote the way the runner is passing while he's accelerating $s_1$, because we want to find the average acceleration we have:

$$s_1 = v_0t + \frac{at_1^2}{2}$$

The initial velocity is 0, so we left out the first term. Also we make a change $a = \frac{\Delta v}{t_1}$

$$s_1 = \frac{\Delta vt_1}{2}$$

We know that $\Delta v = v - v_0$, where $v$ is the maximum reached velocity. We know that $v_0 = 0$, so $\Delta v = v$. Now we get:

$$s_1 = \frac{vt_1}{2}$$

Know let's denote the second part of the way, when the velocity is constant as $s_2$. We have:

$$s_2 = v(t-t_1)$$

We know that the sum of the two distances is $100m$ so we have:

$$s_1 + s_2 = 100$$
$$\frac{vt_1}{2} + v(t-t_1) = 100$$
$$\frac{4.1 \cdot v}{2} + v(9-4.1) = 100$$
$$2.05 \cdot v + 4.9 \cdot v = 100$$
$$6.95 \cdot v = 100$$
$$v = \frac{100m}{6.95s}$$
$$v \approx 14.39m/s$$

Now we substitute back:

$$a = \frac{\Delta v}{t_1} = \frac{v}{t_1} = \frac{14.39}{4.1} \approx 3.51 \frac{m}{s^2}$$

Answer (score 4):

[image]draw a velocity time graph

on the graph start from rest so $v=0$, $t=0$ then increased acceleration till reach speed $v$ and at $t=4.1$ and constant speed v further 4.9 sec

Total Distance = Total area

$$100 = \text{Area of the trapezium} = \frac{a+b}{2} \cdot h$$
 ( a and b are parallel sides of trapezium and h is the height )

\begin{align*}
100&=\frac{9+4.9}{2} \cdot h \\
 v&=14.39 \\
 a&=\frac{v-u}{t} \\
 a&=\frac{14.39-0}{4.1} \\
 a&=3.5 ms^{-2} \\
\end{align*}

Comment: But the question says that the runner travels in total 100m. Can you use the 100m for the 4.1s?

Comment: no 100 m for all 9 sec i am using the area formula for total distance

Comment: now check the picture i have put in 4.1 initially and 4.9 at constant speed( maintaining maximum speed) the maximum speed we do not know find it first and then find acceleration

Answer (score -2):

$$\text{Average velocity} = \frac{\text{Total distance run}}{\text{Total time taken}} = \frac{100}{9} = 11.11\  m/ \sec$$